# 'cin not declared in this scope' error upon compilation

Tags: c++, g++

Here is the code:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    int main() {
        std::cout << "Enter two numbers: " << std::endl;
        int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
        std:cin >> v1 >> v2;
        std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << "and " v2 << "is " << v1+v2 << std:endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
g++ x.cpp 
#x.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
#x.cpp:23:9: error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope
#x.cpp:23:9: note: suggested alternative:
#In file included from x.cpp:19:0:
#/usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:61:18: note:   ‘std::cin’
#x.cpp:24:48: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘v2’
```

---

I have corrected the code, there are several mistakes (this is my first c++ experience):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " and " <<  v2 << " is " << v1+v2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler says there is a problem on line 23.  What is line 23 and why do you expect that it works right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here:

```
std:cin >> v1 >> v2;
// ^
```

You are missing a colon. It should be:

```
std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
// ^^
```

Without the second colon, instead of using the scope resolution operator, you are declaring a *label* called `std`, followed by an unqualified name `cin` (which is why the compiler complains about `cin` not being declared in this scope).